# PNG image is not loading properly in Firefox while loading the ascx page via JavaScript

Tags: html, css, firefox

I am loading the ascx file using JavaScript. When ascx loads the first time, the background image of the window displays properly. When I load it the second time, then background image is not visible. But when I hover on that section, it is again visible.

The issue only occurs in Firefox. It works fine in Chrome.

My HTML:

```
<tr class="adminPopupBGGrey ">
  <td colspan="2" class="adminPopupLines">&nbsp;
  </td>
</tr>
```

CSS:

```
.adminPopupLines
{
    background-image: url(/img/icons/AdminPopupLines.png);
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
    background-position: center;
    height: 2px;
    width: 4px;
}
```

Comment: Maybe you could provide us the code used for loading the ascx?

Comment: Thank you for considering my question @Py....my code is like this : hypEditCompanyWithAddress.NavigateUrl = "javascript:jWDDialog('editaddresstraining?addressId=" + companyAddressObject.AddressId + "')";.....here editaddresstraining is my ascx control